# Reductive Operator Problem

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

In the  1972 paper ''[An equivalent Formulation of the Invariant Subspace Conjecture](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183534143)''  Dyer, Pedersen, and Porcelli announce the following result:

> The Invariant Subspace Problem  has a positive solution if and only if every reductive operator is normal (the Reductive Operator Problem).

This result is cited in a few subsequent papers, as well as in Radjavi and Rosenthal book on Invariant Subspaces.

However, the author do not present proofs in the paper and state:

''Inasmuch as the proof of the result requires an elaborate use
of direct integral theory for rings of operators, **we have not given proofs
to the theorems**. The complete proofs are expected to appear in a forthcoming
monograph on direct integral theory and its applications."

Also

"The proofs of our main results require a great deal of the theory
of direct integral decompositions for von Neumann algebras. The necessary
literature for our use of the theory can be found in [list of references]"

I couldn't find any subsequent monograph where the proofs are presented. Is anybody aware of such monograph, or perhaps another source where I can find the proof of this result?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this sufficient? [Measurable Choice and the Invariant Subspace Problem](https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1097&context=mathfacpub)

Comment: Good find from @CarloBeenakker - the paper was published in the Bull AMS in 1974, see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=361831 for the MathReview and https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1974-13560-3 for the article itself

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you! Yes, this should be sufficient.